# Can we use callkit to make phone call when in development?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

Is it possible to make an in-app phone call using `Callkit` (Not directing user out of the app) when the app has not been launched?

I have already built the app on my physical device, and the sim card is working. I can make phone call outside of the app. But when I make in-app phone call, it simply shows "connected" but the other side doesn't ring. Do I have to launch it to TestFlight to make it work?

edit: I installed Apple callkit demo app and when I dial outgoing call, it is not being received from the other side. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Comment: No,  it callkit calls are nothing to do with the SIM in the device (except in the sense that they may use cellular data if wifi is not available). It sounds like you have a problem with yoir callkit implementation. Is your app communicating with your server correctly?

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried the apple example app, and I believe that it's phone number it wants me to enter right?

Comment: Can you point at the sample code?  I doubt if it is fully functional as it will need a back end server to actually make a call. Callkit does not allow you to make calls using the device SIM number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you'd want to make GSM calls using `CallKit`. If that's the case, you've probably misinterpreted what the capabilities of `CallKit` are.

As stated by the documentation:

> CallKit provides the calling interface, and **you** handle the back-end communication with your VoIP service.

So, you have to build or set up a VoIP back-end service in order to make calls (you can only do VoIP calls). `CallKit` is only responsible for displaying the system-calling UI and coordinate your calling services with other apps and the system.

In addition to that, you also have to support `PushKit` VoIP notifications (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) in order to be able to receive calls while you're app is not running.